# Unable to remove object from string of objects saved in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I have searched for solution to this problem but I have not got an answer, I don't know if it has been answered before however. I got a code online to save objects as JSON string in SharedPreferences using the Gson library and adapted it for use.

The code works fine except for when I need to remove an item from SharedPreferences. The item does not remove. Please help me look into the code. The codes are pasted as shown below.

The object class:

```
public class fPerson {

String name, id, type, cat;

public fPerson(String nm, String ID, String typ, String ct)
{
    this.name = nm;
    this.id = ID;
    this.type = typ;
    this.cat = ct;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
    this.name = n;
}

public void setId(String i)
{
    this.id = i;
}

public void settype(String ty)
{
    this.type = ty;
}

public void setCat(String ct)
{
    this.cat = ct;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public String getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public String getType()
{
    return this.type;
}

public String getCat()
{
    return this.cat;
}

public String toString()
{
    return new String(getName() + " " + getId()+ " " + getType());
}

}
```

The class with the SharedPreferences

```
public class Preferences {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "APP";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite";

public Preferences() {
    super();
}


public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<fPerson> favorites) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    editor.commit();
}

public void addFavorite(Context context, fPerson person) {
    List<fPerson> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<fPerson>();
    favorites.add(person);
    saveFavorites(context, favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, fPerson person) {
    ArrayList<fPerson> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        Iterator<fPerson> iter = favorites.listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            fPerson temp = (fPerson)iter.next();
            if(temp.getId().equals(person.getId()))
            {
                favorites.remove(person);
                break;
            }
        }            
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }
}

public ArrayList<fPerson> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<fPerson> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        fPerson[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, fPerson[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<fPerson>(favorites);

    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<fPerson>) favorites;
}

}
```

Comment: unable to remove data from preference because you are using same key to save all values and trying to delete item from preference using value instead of key.use key FAVORITES to remove value

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not trying to remove the whole string from preference. The string in preference is a string of a JSON array of each object as string. What I want to do is to remove a single object from the JSON array and should be left with a string of JSON array of the remaining objects in preference

Comment: Have you try `editor.clear()` just before `editor.putString()`

Comment: @ja_mesa: Thanks.let me try that and give you a feedback.

Comment: @ja_mesa: I have tried it, it didn't work

Comment: Then, I think, the problem is not in the savePreferences the problem is in the way you remove the object from the list. Are you sure the fPerson object gets removed?

Comment: @ja_mesa: I want to believe the fPerson object gets removed. I am calling the remove function in an onclick method in a list adapter. The arraylist of fperson objects is passed to the list adapter, so the onclicklistener is attached to each of the views inflated in the adapter. I just pass the current arraylist fperson object to the removeFavourite() method for removal

Comment: Well, that's very easy to test. Just put a break point and debug the code or just write a Log with the deleted object. `android.util.Log.w("Object deleted: " + fPerson.tosting());`

Comment: For the purpose of whoever might be having the same challenge, finally got a solution to the problem. Instead of using the removeFavorite() method, what I did was to get the list of fPerson, remove the item I want to and save the list afresh in preferences under the same name like so...fp.remove(rposition);     myPref.saveFavorites(getApplicationContext(), fp); thanks to ja_mesa for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of whoever might be having the same challenge, finally got a solution to the problem. Instead of using the removeFavorite() method, what I did was to get the list of fPerson, remove the item I want to and save the list afresh in preferences under the same name like so...
    fp.remove(rposition); 
    myPref.saveFavorites(getApplicationContext(), fp);